# Node.js AES decryption

Tags: python, node.js, encryption, aes

I have some decryption code in python that I need ported to node.  I cannot seem to get the decryption right and I am going crazy.

My python code is:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

mode = AES.MODE_ECB
secret = "9kL8yb/3Tu2czOr5qfiGPgJmx25s+T15"
cipher = AES.new(secret, mode)

DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(e.decode("hex"))
incoming = '813411aa65dcb66802a6e4d5995d8302'

pre_add = DecodeAES(cipher, incoming)
print pre_add
```

The result of the incoming is 0004a38bc14e7533 which is correct.

I am sorry I am very new to node and javascript.

I need to somehow get the exact same thing working from node.js

I have the following for node so far:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');


var ciphertext = '813411aa65dcb66802a6e4d5995d8302';
var key = '9kL8yb/3Tu2czOr5qfiGPgJmx25s+T15';
var binkey = new Buffer(key, 'binary');


var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-ecb', binkey, '');
decipher.setAutoPadding(auto_padding=true);

var dec = decipher.update(ciphertext, 'hex');
dec += decipher.final();
```

Another update from my understanding of the docs

Please help I am getting desperate.

Many thanks

Jonny

Comment: you realize that your (original, python) code is insecure, right?  look at the wikipedia articule for cipher modes, ecb.

Comment: The encryption is performed on a micro controller.  We didn't have enough memory to use anything better.  The encrypted data is tiny and ends up being a single block

Comment: Don't just say "it doesn't work". Give us some sample data and what you expect the output to be, describe the errors or incorrect results that you get, etc.

Comment: But meanwhile… given that your Python code is calling `e.decode("hex")` and you're not doing anything even remotely equivalent in Node, I wouldn't expect it to work out very well…

Comment: added edit with required result and the error is TypeError: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt

Comment: Unauthenticated ECB mode encryption is highly vulnerable to replay attacks.

Comment: not worried about replay attacks as the data includes the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody is going to just port your Python code to JavaScript. Especially your bizarrely non-Pythonic Python code (why would you ever do `foo = lambda blah` instead of just `def foo(blah)`?).

But here's how to get started:

Node.js comes with a module called [`crypto`](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) that is, not too surprisingly, similar in functionality to the PyCrypto module you're using.

The Node module has separate objects for ciphering and deciphering, unlike Python. The function to create a cipher is called [`crypto.createCipher`](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipher_algorithm_password), and to create a decipher is `crypto.createDecipher`.

As the documentation says, the objects you get back from those functions are read-write streams. You write encrypted data to the `Decipher` stream, and read decrypted data.

---

Meanwhile, this ridiculously silly line of Python code:

```
DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(e.decode("hex"))
```

… is probably easier to read if you write it like this:

```
def DecodeAES(cipher, hexdata):
    bindata = hexdata.decode("hex")
    return cipher.decrypt(bindata)
```

You may notice that it does two things to the incoming hex data. But your attempted equivalent Node code only does one of those two things. That isn't likely to work.

---

In your new version of the Node code, you do this:

```
var BinCipher = new Buffer(ciphertext, 'binary');
```

That's apparently supposed to do the same thing as the Python:

```
bindata = hexdata.decode("hex")
```

It obviously doesn't, because you didn't put the `hex` anywhere. Try printing it out to see what you get:

```
> console.log(BinCipher)
<Buffer 65 35 38 31 61 63 62 38 33 30 30 64 64 38 34 31 38 33 33 30 30 39 64 65 36 37 33 36 37 35 39 33>
```

Clearly, that `65` is the letter `e`, the `35` is the digit `5`, etc. You haven't unhexlified anything. Compare to the Python version:

```
>>> print repr(bindata)
'\xe5\x81\xac\xb80\r\xd8A\x830\t\xdeg6u\x93'
```

Here, the first character is `\xe5`, the next is `\x81`. That's what you want.

And I'm not even sure why you think you need a `Buffer` in the first place. If you read the docs I linked to above, they clearly show that you can pass "`'binary'`, `'base64'`, or `'hex'`" input and output encodings straight to the `Decipher` methods.

Comment: I have been trying that for hours now, I always get bad decrypt errors. I didn't write the original python code.  
What I have for node so far uses that but I must be missing something.

Comment: I have changed the python to your suggestion and attempted some changes to the node I have edited the question with the new code.  Still getting the bad decrypt error

Comment: Where did you get that `new Buffer(ciphertext, 'binary')` from? That doesn't unhexlify your hex data, and I don't understand why you would think it did. And if you did any kind of debugging (e.g., just `console.log(BinCipher)` in Node and `print repr(bindata)` in Python) it would be pretty obvious they weren't doing the same thing. You can't write code by just copying and pasting lines from random places that you don't understand.

Comment: How would I convert that hex to binary then?  printing the bindata statement from python yields ?4?eܶh??ՙ]?

Comment: I'll give you a hint: The documentation that I linked to and then quoted from mentions the encodings 'binary', 'base64', and 'hex'. Which one do you think decodes from hex in the same way as the one Python calls 'hex'?

Comment: I have updated the code from my understanding of the documents.  I am sorry if I seem stupid but I am trying to wrap my head around javascript and seem to failing miserably.